# URL with dot causes 404 error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.Net Web Api application which takes ip address as input and return the country of that respective ip.
when I pass the below url

```
http://localhost:portno/xx.xx.xx.xx
```

it throws `Error 404`

can any one tell me why?

Comment: can you post your code for controller actions ?

Answer (score 6):

Short hacky answer: Add a trailing forward slash. IIS thinks it's a file at the end of hte URL.

Longer, more elegant answer: Check out these links for cleaner fixes that require more work:

[ApiController returns 404 when ID contains period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298542/apicontroller-returns-404-when-id-contains-period)

[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)